# get node element by model property angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is a way to get the input that binding a model's property.

I want to do this to blur the search input after I send the form, 
and I want to do this dynamically for later changes in html source.

**Example:**

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.term = 'test';
  $scope.submit = function(){
    document.querySelector('#search').blur();
    // I want replace document.querySelector('#search') with something like 'getElementByProp($scope.term)'
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div data-ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form data-ng-submit="submit()">
  <input id="search" type="search" data-ng-model="term" />
  </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want to select element by model name, or model value?

Comment: model name (the name of the property)

Comment: then you can use `document.querySelector()`: `document.querySelector('[data-ng-model="term"]')`

Comment: I know this. My question is not only for this scenario, but to know if there is option in angular itself.

Comment: hm. then I don't think there is an option except creating a directive and use `element` there.

Comment: First, you should not manipulate the DOM in a controller. What you can do is change something in the model, that will cause the change in the view. For this bit more complex perquisite, you'd like to setup a directive to do the job for you (e.g. a blur directive, that will be activated with a certain condition in the model).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a fundamental error in your intention here.

Please keep the following always in mind:
**The controller should know absolutely nothing about the DOM**

This is a precious rule of thumb that will help you a lot.

Now, of course you need to interact with the DOM from your javascript (AngularJS code), and for that you should use Directives.

In your case though I would use another approach:

```
if (document.activeElement) {
  document.activeElement.blur();
}
```

This will work for any focused elements and you won't need to specifically query any DOM element.
So in theory you're not giving the controller any knowledge about the DOM, so for me this doesn't break the rule I mentioned above.

Just as a side note, $document for some reaon doesn't expose this activeElement.
I don't have time to dig into the code to see why but as far as I've tested you need to stick with the native document object.

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to do this is using the jQuery little version that comes with AngularJS.

Try this:

```
var element = angular.element('[ng-model="YOUR_MODEL_NAME_HERE"]');
element.blur(); // element is a jQuery object
```

This should work

Comment: I tried this but it gives me error: `Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!`  But whats weird, is if I do: `var el = document.getElementById(id); angular.element(el).on("click", function() { ... } ;`  MY real issue is that I am trying to retrieve  `<div id='divID'>` that exists out side of `<ion-content>` - can't figure out how to get to it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is not possible is that this is not something you'll usually want to do in Angular - you're most likely still "thinking like you're using jQuery". Please elaborate on why you want to manipulate the DOM yourself in the first place. Most likely it's a different problem that you can solve with e.g. a directive.

(This may sound like a lame answer, but "don't do this" very likely is the only correct way to handle this situation.)

Comment: The specific use is that when the form is submitted, the input field will no longer be in focus. To close the keyboard mobile devices. There is more uses..

Comment: Ideally, this is not something that you would have to do yourself. Have you tested it? My mobile browser closes the keyboard by itself when I submit a form.

Even still, this is not something you would want to be doing in the controller, as AlexCode says. You'd probably be making your own special input directive that handles this. However, you can feel it coming: you'd be starting to make custom directives for every form element to do something that you shouldn't have to implement yourself. I would check if there might be another reason the keyboard is not closed.